# Display all months even if values are NULL

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a chart where I need to display all the Months in a year to show the sales per month.  So far, I am able to display only the Month where there are corresponding values. Here is my Stored Procedure query so far.

```
SELECT (DATENAME (MONTH, DATEADD ( MONTH, DATEPART(MONTH, ORDER_DATE), -1) ))
AS MONTH_NAME,
  SUM ([ORDER].NET_AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_SALES
  FROM [ORDER], ORDER_DETAILS
  WHERE [ORDER].ORDER_ID = ORDER_DETAILS.ORDER_ID
  --AND (DATENAME (MONTH, DATEADD ( MONTH, DATEPART(MONTH, ORDER_DATE), -1) )) = (DATENAME (MONTH, DATEADD ( MONTH, DATEPART(MONTH, @Order_month), -1) )) 
  GROUP BY MONTH([ORDER].ORDER_DATE)
  ORDER BY MONTH_NAME
```

It displays only 1 month and the sales for that month. Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: If the missing months are not part of your dataset, then you will have to introduce that data somehow, possibly using a calendar table.

Comment: I'll work on that. Thank you Sir!

Comment: Sight detour...your join syntax is out of date for close to 30 years now. Might be time to consider using a more "modern" style join. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: a potential problem with GROUP BY MONTH(o.ORDER_DATE) is that it will group items together if they are from the same month number in different years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first please use proper JOIN syntax and aliases.

You can create CTE with months and CTE with your output and join them:

```
;WITH mcte AS (
    SELECT CAST('2016-01-01' as datetime) as MONTH_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,MONTH_NAME)
    FROM mcte
    WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,MONTH_NAME) < 12
), octe AS (
    SELECT  (DATENAME (MONTH, DATEADD ( MONTH, DATEPART(MONTH, ORDER_DATE), -1) )) AS MONTH_NAME,
            SUM (o.NET_AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_SALES
    FROM [ORDER] o
    INNER JOIN ORDER_DETAILS od
        ON o.ORDER_ID = od.ORDER_ID
        --AND (DATENAME (MONTH, DATEADD ( MONTH, DATEPART(MONTH, ORDER_DATE), -1) )) = (DATENAME (MONTH, DATEADD ( MONTH, DATEPART(MONTH, @Order_month), -1) )) 
    GROUP BY MONTH(o.ORDER_DATE)
)


SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH,m.MONTH_NAME) as MONTH_NAME,
        o.TOTAL_SALES
FROM mcte m
LEFT JOIN octe o
    ON o.MONTH_NAME = DATENAME(MONTH,m.MONTH_NAME)
```

This will gave all month names and all total sales, if there are no total sales - it will show NULLs.

Comment: Hi @gofr1 ! I'm having a problem with this line **m.DATENAME(MONTH,MONTH_NAME)** . The error says **Cannot find either column "m" or the user-defined function or aggregate "m.DATENAME", or the name is ambiguous**

Comment: Hi! Sorry, it was my typo. `ON o.MONTH_NAME = m.DATENAME(MONTH,MONTH_NAME)` should be `ON o.MONTH_NAME = DATENAME(MONTH,m.MONTH_NAME)`, Changed in my answer!

Comment: Hi! @gofr1 ! This did the job for me, the thing is, it display the MONTH_NAME in datetime format. I need it to be displayed as the Month Name itself. I tried to alter this line, **SELECT CAST('2016-01-01' as datetime) as MONTH_NAME** but I couldn't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 5):

Create a table of months

```
    Create table #months
    (
    monthid int,
    monthname varchar(100)
    )

    insert into #monthids
    (monthid,monthname)
    values
    (1,'January'),(2,'February')...insert upto 12 months


;with cte
as
(
SELECT 
(DATENAME (MONTH, DATEADD ( MONTH, DATEPART(MONTH, ORDER_DATE), -1) ))
AS MONTH_NAME,
SUM ([ORDER].NET_AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_SALES
FROM [ORDER], ORDER_DETAILS
WHERE [ORDER].ORDER_ID = ORDER_DETAILS.ORDER_ID
(DATENAME (MONTH, DATEADD ( MONTH, DATEPART(MONTH, @Order_month), -1) )) 
GROUP BY MONTH([ORDER].ORDER_DATE)
)
select 
m.Monthname,
isnull(total_Sales,0) as 'totalSales'
from #months m
Left join
cte c
on c.monthname=m.month_name
```

Comment: Is **#months** just a temp table?

Comment: yes,depending on your data,you can create as permanent table as well

Comment: **select 
m.Monthname,
isnull(total_Sales,0) as 'totalSales'
from #monthids m
cte c
on c.monthname=m.month_name**

I am passing this to a JsonResult Method, I will have pass 3 parameters because of **'totalSales'** ?

Comment: @KylieIrwin:Can you please elaborate

Comment: How would you modify this code to include a unique CUST_ID field? And Does it need to be included in the join in addition to month?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT (DATENAME (MONTH, DATEADD ( MONTH, DATEPART(MONTH, ORDER_DATE), -1) ))
AS MONTH_NAME,
  SUM ([ORDER].NET_AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_SALES
  FROM [ORDER], ORDER_DETAILS
  WHERE [ORDER].ORDER_ID(+) = ORDER_DETAILS.ORDER_ID
  --AND (DATENAME (MONTH, DATEADD ( MONTH, DATEPART(MONTH, ORDER_DATE), -1) ))            = (DATENAME (MONTH, DATEADD ( MONTH, DATEPART(MONTH, @Order_month), -1) )) 
  GROUP BY MONTH([ORDER].ORDER_DATE)
  ORDER BY MONTH_NAME
```

Comment: Hi! I tried this but it says, ** Incorrect syntax near ')' ** What is the **(+)** for?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, its not oracle, you are using sql server. You should use #TheGameiswar ' s answer

Comment: `(+)` is the mark of an outer join.